# Django unable to set IntegerField on Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am not a professional Django user, I will try to described this problem as concise as I can.

I have a Django Serializer definition:

```
class PrioritisedMarketActionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   marketaction = MarketActionSerializer(required=True)
   priority = serializers.IntegerField()
```

and the definition of MarketActionSerializer is

```
class MarketActionClearingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

class Meta:
    model = MarketAction

    fields = (
        'id', 'date', 'actionStartTime', 'actionEndTime', 'value', 'uom', 'price', 'deliveryPoint',
        'marketSessionid',
        'marketActorid', 'formid', 'actionTypeid', 'statusid', 'loadid', 'cpu', 'ram', 'disk',)
    depth = 0
    error_status_codes = {
        HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: 'Bad Request',
        HTTP_201_CREATED: 'Created',
        HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT: 'No content',
        HTTP_301_MOVED_PERMANENTLY: 'Moved permanently',
        HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED: 'Unauthorized',
        HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN: 'Forbidden',
        HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND: 'Not found',
        HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR: 'Internal server error'
    }
```

My objective is to create a list of these serializers objects, after I received through a POST method a list of  MarketAction objects. I declare an empty list where to store these objects:

```
output = []
```

Then, iterating over the received objects:

```
prioritised_ma["marketaction"] = MarketActionSerializer(ma).data
prioritised_ma["priority"] = 1


output.append(PrioritisedMarketActionsSerializer(prioritised_ma).data)
```

The ["priority"] field was set to 1, {int}, for testing purposes. However, when I call:

```
PrioritisedMarketActionsSerializer(prioritised_ma).data
```

I get this strange error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

The full associated stack trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlad/Documents/Research Projects/Catalyst Marketplace/GitProjects/orchestrator/information_broker/ib/views/api.py", line 709, in post
  output.append(PrioritisedMarketSerializer(prioritised_ma_clearing).data)
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 563, in data
    ret = super(Serializer, self).data
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 530, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 530, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/vlad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 272, in to_representation
    return value.pk
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I assume the error is related to the "priority" field, which is the {int} value, but I can not figure it out.

Could someone help me please, or give me a hint towards what am I doing wrong here? I would deeply appreciate it.

Thank you very much, I wish you a wonderful day!

Comment: Please show full error traceback

Comment: Potential [dupicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539341/drf-attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-pk)

Comment: Greetings Ivan. 
I have updated the question to contain the full stack trace. Thank you!

Comment: rob, mine is not a models.Serializer, I am trying to build a serializer from a standard dict

Comment: Try setting `prioritised_ma["marketaction"] = ma` instead of serialization result. Also please show `MarketActionSerializer` definition. Note, `prioritised_ma_clearing` mentioned is not defined in shown code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue

Thanks to @Ivan Starostin for pointing me in the right direction.

As the:

```
class PrioritisedMarketActionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    marketaction = MarketActionSerializer(required=True)
    priority = serializers.IntegerField()
```

expected a `MarketActionSerializer` object for the `marketaction` attribute, I was mistakenly giving it `MarketActionSerializer.data`.

To solve the issue, I have checked the correct format of the marketaction using `MarketActionSerializer(ma).is_valid()`, but I have used the dict object, `ma`, in the instantioation of `PrioritisedMarketActionSerializer`.

The solution is something like the following:

```
if MarketActionSerializer(data=ma).is_valid():
    prioritised_ma["marketaction"] = ma
    prioritised_ma["priority"] = 1
    prioritised_marke_action = PrioritisedMarketActionSeializer(prioritised_ma).data
```

Thank you everyone for guiding me to solve this issue and better understand Djano. Special thanks to @Ivan Starostin.