# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk' - Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return a very simple serialised queryset and I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'

**Models:**

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)


class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name="images", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    thumb = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**View:**

```
class PortfolioViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.PortfolioSerializer
    queryset = models.Portfolio.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, core_permissions.IsMineOnly)

    def get_queryset(self):
        portfolios = self.request.user.portfolio_set.all()
        ser = self.serializer_class(portfolios, many=True)
        data = ser.data

        return data
```

**serialisers:**

```
class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Portfolio
        exclude = ('user',)


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57710845/6855056) answer that says we should use validated_data after calling `is_valid()` first but I don't serialise data but a queryset so I can't call this method.

Answer (score 1):

`get_queryset` should return queryset.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.request.user.portfolio_set.all()
```

Comment: Yeah but I want to perform some operations before returning the queryset, is there any other method I can use?

Comment: Can you share what operations exactly? In this case you need to make sure you always return a queryset in `get_queryset`, and do the other operations (like serializing) in another part of the view